# Is it okay to load an Ad and not show it?

Tags: android, admob

Is it okay to load Interstital Ad every time user opens up one Activity, even if it is shown every 4-th opening or only when user clicks on certain button (which means that ad may never really be shown). In my case I am using:

```
 mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
```

in OnCreate() which means that i load more ads, that are going to be shown. I've tried creating counter and loading ad only when it is 4-th opening, but they load to slow to be shown and I am getting no ads.

Comment: It seems you want to display hidden ads and get revenue from it, and make your apps look like more premium. This is prohibited by Google, and you apps can be removed from Play Store.

Answer (score 0):

Loading the ad prior to be displayed is a best practise. I don't see any restriction to always show the ad if it's once loaded

> Allow for adequate loading time. Just as it's important to make sure
>   you display interstitial ads at an appropriate time, it's also
>   important to make sure the user doesn't have to wait for them to load.
>   Loading the ad in advance by calling loadAd() before you intend to
>   call show() can ensure that your app has a fully loaded interstitial
>   ad at the ready when the time comes to display one.

Best practises [here](https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial)